# HTML text input not updating with Knockout Bindings

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, html-input

I am trying to automatically add slashes for a DOB input field but Knockout bindings are not playing nice.

```html
<input 
name=x 
size=10 
maxlength=10 
class="span12" 
placeholder="Date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY)"
  onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')"
  data-bind="value:visitor().dateOfBirth, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
```

The issue now is that the Knockout Js bindings are not allowing the slashes value to be automatically updated. When I enter dates in the text box no slashes show up. How do I set up a subscriber for myViewModel to modify the value whenever it changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something along these lines - note you should remove the inlined `onkeyup` from your `input` tag and let your view model handle it:

```js
var vm = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.dateOfBirth = ko.observable();
  self.insertSlashes = function () {
     var currentValue = self.dateOfBirth();
     self.dateOfBirth(currentValue
        .replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g,'$1/$2')
        .replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g,'$1/$2')
        .replace(/[^\d\/]/g,'')
    );
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input 
  placeholder="Date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY)"
  data-bind="value: dateOfBirth, valueUpdate:'keyup', event: { keyup: insertSlashes } " 
/>
```